# for loop specific elements of a vector in R

Tags: r

I want to run a for loop which makes a calculation only for specific elements from a column in a data frame. The elements are referenced from an adjacent column in the matrix. I can do this by visually observing which elements correspond to the values - e.g. `for(i in 1:5){ #` in a column of 301 elements. However, I would like to be able to specify this without apriori knowledge of the element numbers.

e.g. in the following data frame I want to run a for loop on the elements of the column `data.LICOR$flux` when `data.LICOR$day.night=='d'`

```
   data.LICOR.day.night data.LICOR.flux
1                   d       26.89
2                   d       27.89
3                   d       28.77
4                   d       28.92
5                   d       29.30
6                   n       28.51
7                   n       28.98
8                   n       28.41
9                   n       27.87
10                  n       28.18
```

This is what my previous code did by specifying element 1:5 and 6:10 which correspond to day.night = 'd' and day.night ='n' respectively

```
# replace day fluxes
for(i in 1:5){
    if(data.LICOR$flux[i] > av.day.flux+2*sd.day.flux)
      data.LICOR$flux[i] <- av.day.flux
    else if(data.LICOR$flux[i] < av.day.flux-2*sd.day.flux)
      data.LICOR$flux[i] <- av.day.flux 
}

# replace night fluxes
for(i in 6:10){
    if(data.LICOR$flux[i] > av.night.flux+2*sd.night.flux)
      data.LICOR$flux[i] <- av.night.flux
    else if(data.LICOR$flux[i] < av.night.flux-2*sd.night.flux) 
      data.LICOR$flux[i] <- av.night.flux 
}
```

this removes values that are greater than 2 standard deviations from the mean and replaces them with the mean value.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Suggestion 1) provide more information so we can help you avoid unnecessary for loops.

Comment: What do you want to do in the for loop? It is highly likely you don't need a loop at all and can use a vectorised operation on the subset of `data.YSI` given by `subset(data.YSI, subset = day.night == "d")`

Comment: Please use the code sample button when posting data/code. It looks like `{}` and it will make your data/code much more readable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given the loops in your comment to Gavin's answer, I think you want something like this (assuming your example data are in an object named `data.LICOR`).

```
# within() allows us to evaluate all the expressions (the 2nd argument)
# using the data in 'data.LICOR'.
data.LICOR <- within(data.LICOR, {
  # ave() applies 'FUN' to the subsets of 'flux' specified by 'day.night'
  # and returns an object the same length as 'flux'.
  av.flux <- ave(flux, day.night, FUN=mean);
  sd.flux <- ave(flux, day.night, FUN=sd);
  # ifelse() returns 'av.flux' when the first argument is TRUE
  # and 'flux' when it's FALSE.
  flux <- ifelse(flux > av.flux+2*sd.flux |
                 flux < av.flux-2*sd.flux, av.flux, flux) })
```

Comment: Hi, I ameded the question slightly. Where in this code are the removed values replaced by the mean values? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Gab_27: the last 2 lines do it. `ifelse` is a vectorized, element-by-element way to compare objects. I'll add some comments to my answer...

Comment: Brilliant. Thats a very concise way doing what the for loop did previously. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Gab_27 the last line with `ifelse(....` says if flux is greater than 2 times the sd of flux *larger* than the mean, or (the `|` is "or") greater than 2 times the sd of flux *smaller* than the mean, return `av.flux`, if not, return `flux`, the observed data.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `subset` function to get the subset of the data-frame you want. E.g. if `df` is your original data-frame, you can do:

```
df.d <- subset(df, day.night == 'd')
```

And then you can do whatever calc you want on `df.d`.
To replace the "large" and "small" values by their mean, you could do it in base R using Joshua's approach (using `ave` and `within`) or using the `ddply` function from the `plyr` package:

```
require(plyr)
## ddply breaks up the data-frame according to the value of "DayNight" ('d' or 'n') and 
## WITHIN each category, "transforms" the flux column as desired
ddply(df, .(DayNight), transform,
      flux = ifelse( flux > mean(flux) + 2*sd(flux) | flux < mean(flux) - 2*sd(flux),
                     mean(flux),
                     flux ))
```

I'm using shortened versions of your column names, but I'm sure you get the idea. If you know the "right" level of the average and std deviation *a priori*, you can replace the `mean(flux)` and `sd(flux)` in the above code, with those values.

Comment: Thanks...Actually I second your comment asking the OP about what they are intending to do with the "for loop", so we can help them do it looplessly... which is probably the more interesting problem!

Comment: for(i in 1:127){if(data.LICOR$flux[i]>av.day.flux+2*sd.day.flux) data.LICOR$flux[i]<-av.day.flux else if(data.LICOR$flux[i]<av.day.flux-2*sd.day.flux) data.LICOR$flux[i]<-av.day.flux}
  
# replace night fluxes
for(i in 128:301){if(data.LICOR$flux[i]>av.night.flux+2*sd.night.flux) data.LICOR$flux[i]<-av.night.flux else if(data.LICOR$flux[i]<av.night.flux-2*sd.night.flux) data.LICOR$flux[i]<-av.night.flux} this runs through the column $flux and removes values greater than 2 standard deviations from the mean of the corresponding day/night,replaces them with the mean of those values.

Comment: So I will need to subset the data frame into subset = day.night=='d' and subset = day.night=='n'. Is that possible also?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the subset using:

```
subset(data.YSI, subset = day.night == "d")
```

But now tell us what you want to do with it?

Comment: Ok thanks this is what I am trying to do:for(i in 1:127){
 if(data.LICOR$flux[i]>av.day.flux+2*sd.day.flux) data.LICOR$flux[i]<-av.day.flux  else
  if(data.LICOR$flux[i]<av.day.flux-2*sd.day.flux) data.LICOR$flux[i]<-av.day.flux 
  }
  
# replace night fluxes
for(i in 128:301){
 if(data.LICOR$flux[i]>av.night.flux+2*sd.night.flux) data.LICOR$flux[i]<- av.night.flux else
  if(data.LICOR$flux[i]<av.night.flux-2*sd.night.flux) data.LICOR$flux[i]<-  av.night.flux 
  }

Comment: @Gab_27: Ouch my eyes are hurting! Please post this in the original question :)

Comment: @Gab_27 blimey, could you edit your Q to include this code and **space** it out so it is readable! By the looks of it though, the manipulations you want should be relatively easy to do vectorised

Comment: Sorry, im new to this forum. I have amended the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility for the last two lines of the answer provided by Ulrich is:

```
 flux[which(flux> av.flux+2*sd.flux & flux < av.flux-2*sd.flux)] <- av.flux
```

This is, arguably, faster, because you only need to replace those values which do not fit the criteria. However, I'm not sure if this is truly faster in R, and for small datasets I guess it won't matter.

And kepping the loop (not a good practice in R if it's possible to vectorize, but may be in other languages), you just need to do this:

```
for (i in unique(data.Licor$day.night) { 
      if (data.LICOR$flux[which(data.LICOR$day.night==i)] > ...
```

Note here that the modifications are: the use of which and use of factors in the for statement.

Comment: nothing wrong with loops in R if there isn't a vectorised way to do it, and you pre-allocate sufficient storage before entering the loop.

Comment: You're right Gavin. What I meant was that looping is not a good practice if it's possible to vectorize. I will edit my answer, thanks.